# Temporal clauses for repeated activities

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple, subordinate-clauses

Which one is the correct form?

1. Whenever I visit her, she is working in her garden.
2. Whenever I visit her, she works in her garden.

(1) seems to break the rule that Present Continuous should be used only for an activity taking place now. (2) seems a bit weird, as working is a continous activity interrupted (possibly) by the visit.

Answer (score 1):

1. states that you find her working in her garden each time you visit her. That's to say that she spends most of her time in the garden and that's where you generally encounter her.
2. suggests that she reacts to your arrival by choosing to work in her garden. It's the way that she deals with your appearance. It is like saying: **Whenever I visit her, she puts on light music.**

Comment: 2 could also mean that at some point(s) during each of your visits to her, she works on the garden. If you often visited for a long time for example and she always worked on the garden at least once while you were there